Improve performance on query with many OR operations
I have the below query where I need to Select the MAX(COST_DATE) per C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, but I don't want to Group On A.REC_TRXN_ID, B.TRANSACTION_ID, A.QUANTITY_ONHAND, or B.TRANSACTION_COST.
(SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
        ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
        A.REC_TRXN_ID,
        B.TRANSACTION_ID,
        B.COST_DATE,
        A.QUANTITY_ONHAND,
        B.TRANSACTION_COST
        FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
             CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
             CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
        WHERE 1=1
            AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
            AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
            AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
            AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
            AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                           
            AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID                             
    ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
    )
    --WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)

Current Results:
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   SUBINVENTORY_CODE   REC_TRXN_ID TRANSACTION_ID  COST_DATE  QUANTITY_ONHAND  TRANSACTION_COST
100000030624440     11XDC               10727447    10727447        2024-01-23  3        17.4375
100000030624440     41XDC               9532105     9532105         2023-11-05  6        17.43
100000030624440     41XDC               9532105     9532105         2023-11-05  6        17.43
100000030624440     41XDC               9532105     9532105         2023-11-04  6        17.43
100000030624440     11XDC               8790246     8790246         2023-09-18  5      17.4375
100000030624440     11XDC               8659489     8659489         2023-09-08  4      17.4375
100000030624440     11XDC               8659489     8659489         2023-09-08  4      17.4375

Desired Results:
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   SUBINVENTORY_CODE   REC_TRXN_ID TRANSACTION_ID  COST_DATE  QUANTITY_ONHAND  TRANSACTION_COST
100000030624440     11XDC               10727447    10727447        2024-01-23  3        17.4375
100000030624440     41XDC               9532105     9532105         2023-11-05  6        17.43

Because I have to Group on the fields A.REC_TRXN_ID, B.TRANSACTION_ID, A.QUANTITY_ONHAND B.TRANSACTION_COST that is preventing me from getting just the MAX Cost Date by only Subinventory. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Also, A, B and C are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, e.g. O for CST_ONHAND_V.

And note table tables have columns, not fields.

with ROW_NUMBER() we can assign a row number to each row within each SUBINVENTORY_CODE partition, ordered by COST_DATE in descending order and then, filter out only the rows with row number 1, which corresponds to the maximum COST_DATE for each SUBINVENTORY_CODE:
SELECT INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
       REC_TRXN_ID,
       TRANSACTION_ID,
       COST_DATE,
       QUANTITY_ONHAND,
       TRANSACTION_COST
FROM (
    SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
           C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
           A.REC_TRXN_ID,
           B.TRANSACTION_ID,
           B.COST_DATE,
           A.QUANTITY_ONHAND,
           B.TRANSACTION_COST,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC) AS rn
    FROM CST_ONHAND_V A
    JOIN CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B ON A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID AND A.REC_TRXN_ID = B.TRANSACTION_ID
    JOIN CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C ON A.REC_TRXN_ID = C.REC_TRXN_ID
    WHERE A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
    ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE rn = 1;


Does this result in any performance issues using this Window function? This SQL is part of a larger query as a CTE.

@Nick using window functions can sometimes introduce performance considerations, especially when dealing with large datasets or complex queries. however, they are often necessary to achieve specific results, such as getting the maximum value per group without losing other columns in the selection. alternative could be Indexed View (if supported by your database)
